# Rails HTML5 creating/customizing date fields form tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I'm trying to follow this awesome tutorial on additional rails form helpers [on using other fields](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/new-html5-form-input-helpers-rails-4-countdown-to-2013).

I'm trying to do a date_field with a label. Here's my current code:

```
.form-group.col-md-12
  =f.label :from_due_date, :label => "From:"
  =f.date_field :from_due_date, :as => :date, :start_date => Date.today.year - 20, :end_date => Date.today.year
  =f.input_field :from_due_date, as: :hidden, :value => Date.today

  =f.label :to_due_date, :label => "To:"
  =f.date_field :to_due_date, :as => :date, :start_date => Date.today.year - 20, :end_date => Date.today.year
  =f.input_field :to_due_date, as: :hidden, :value => Date.today
```

Is there a way that I can mimick what date_field does using input fields or date_select and conform to my ccs style?

[image: This is how it currently looks like]

I tried applying `:label_html => { :class => "col-md-2 text-right" }, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" }` but it really won't change its class. Why is that? I need it to align on other input fields that I have. This code in this paragraph is what I'm using on the other input fields.

What does date_field consist of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add your class as direct *cl*

```
  =f.date_field :to_due_date, class: "form-control"
```

Comment: almost. applying my form-control to date_field takes up the whole form container. Tried adding `:wrapper => :field_multi2` but it also won't work. Am I doing it right? Thanks in advance. Beginner here D: